# Spring jdbctemplate close connections upon application shutdown?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am seeing DB connections not being closed upon application shutdown.

We are using Spring org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcTemplate, and have configured a connection pool. Example Context xml for Tomcat is this:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/fooResource"
        auth="Container"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        validationQuery="select 1 from DUAL"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        username="user"
        password="password"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema"
        maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="10"/>
```

My Spring  bean definition has this snippet:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id = "dataSource"
     jndi-name = "jdbc/fooResource"
      expected-type = "javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Observations:

1. MySQL is started up, it shows Connections : 6.
2. Started up Tomcat with my one web app, and in MySQL, I now see Connections: 16.
3. Stopped Tomcat and the 16 Connections remain.
4. I stop/start Tomcat and the Connections just keep climbing (I guess by 10 since initialSize is 10 by default?)

Questions:

1. I am reading in the docs that using Spring JdbcTemplate takes care of connections (fetching and releasing them to the pool)  but what happens on shutdown -- are my connections supposed to be all closed on shutdown?
2. Am I supposed to do anything else to ensure all DB connections are closed upon application shutdown?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using a pool, from a application standpoint the connections are closed, but the internal of the connection pools don't actually close the connections they return them to the pool. So basically it works as expected.

Comment: That would make sense while the application is up and running, that connections are returned to the pool, but one would expect the connections to be completely closed after the application is shut down, no?

Comment: No why. For the application they are already closed. It knows nothing about the connection pool only a `DataSource` and from the application point of view everything has been done to manage the connections properly.

Comment: I see, thank you. So ultimately the DB is the one that should "close" all these connections then?

Answer (score 2):

If you create the application context manually, you need to register a shutdown hook on the application context.  When you start the app, get a reference to the context and add this line

```
context.registerShutdownHook();
```

If you don't do this, destruction events aren't triggered.

Comment: Implement `ApplicationContextAware` and you can have the context injected into a bean.

Comment: I found that I had to cast ApplicationContext to ConfigurableApplicationContext in order to do this